# Jquery Tabs UI with Auto Collapse Instead of OnClick

Tags: jquery

I need your jquery help.

This is a table which contains a jquery UI tabs section in the middle. The table row currently shows/hides the UI tabs with an 'onclick'.

The help I need solved is to make the table row hide what's meant to be the "hidden" tabbed section automatically *after* the page loads and then the user can expand the tabs like normal with a click. Can someone easily solve this issue real quick?

Please watch my screen cast for a demonstration: http://screencast.com/t/AAxUitL9O7

Check out my fiddle with the HTML/Jquery: http://fiddle.jshell.net/rk7y4/11/

This is the current implementation:

```
 function CollaspeAll() {
        if ($(".ChildRow")[0]) {
            $('tr.ChildRow').children('td').each(function () {

                $(this).children('div').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).css('display') == 'block') {
                        $(this).css("display", "none");
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        $('img').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('src') == 'http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/834/minusl.png') {
                $(this).attr('src', 'http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/6042/plusk.png');
            }
        });
    }
    function ExpandCollapse(TESTID) {
        $('#tabs' + TESTID).tabs();
        if ($('#div' + TESTID)) {

            // Is already ChildGrid shown. If not shown
            if (!isDisplayed($('#div' + TESTID))) {
                if ($('#hid' + TESTID).val() == '0') {
                    $('#div' + TESTID).css("display", "block");
                    $('#img' + TESTID).attr('src', 'http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/834/minusl.png');
                    $('#hid' + TESTID).val("1");
                }
                else {
                    $('#div' + TESTID).css("display", "block");
                    $('#img' + TESTID).attr('src', 'http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/834/minusl.png');
                }
            }
            else { // Already Child Grid Shown
                $('#div' + TESTID).css("display", "none");
                $('#img' + TESTID).attr('src', 'http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/6042/plusk.png');
            }
        }
    }
    function isDisplayed(object) {
        // if the object is visible return true
        if ($(object).css('display') == 'block') {
            return true;
        }
        // if the object is not visible return false
        return false;
    };

    $(".hand").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("blue");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("blue");
    });
```